# Calling a Struts action of one application in other different application

Tags: html, struts2, action

I have a struts based application1(purely in java) which uses .vm for page design like dashboard(charts,graph etc.) Now I have another application2 (php) where I would like to call the dashboard page of application1 in application2. The application1 also asks for  login credentials.

Comment: What do you mean by app1 calls app2 dashboard? that user is in app1 and app2 dashboard is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can always call Struts2 action from your PHP code by use of URL and any additional parameters can only be passed as Query string.

for example if you want to call a action namely 'my-action' of your struts2 application you need to hit URL something like

```
www.yourapplication.com/my-action
```

all you need to have the action configuration in your struts.xml file to send request to respected action.
Any additional parameters can be passed as query string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have full idea about your application. But as per my understanding you are calling java in PHP. you have already logged in in PHP, but while hitting java application it is not looking for your login credentials, again it is asking for login.

As per my idea, while calling java you have to pass the login credentials to the java, otherwise it can't understand. Because applications are different. What you can while calling java, inside code you have a login details like username and password keep both in html hidden field as which paramers are you are handling in java. Based on hidden field parameter name in java it will take login credentials automatically....

**HTML**:

```
<input name="username" value="anitha">
```

**Struts2.action**:

```
//setters/getters

private String username;
```